# Help identify this worm-like thing

Tags: zoology, species-identification

Many instances of this worm-like creature were found in a water system for a mountain cabin in the Sierra Nevada mountains of the US, in late June / early July.  The water system collects water from an enclosed spring.  Can you help identify this creature?

Clues:

1. The worms have two "points" on their heads.
2. They can stretch out and be long and thin, or when poked (or are resting) they contract into a small blob.
3. Here is a picture of a single worm with markings shown.
   [image]
4. Here is a picture of a few worms, somewhat contracted.
   [image]
5. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCBjzdkL7lA&authuser=0) is a movie of them moving, in natural light.
6. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgaZMEjlLK0&authuser=0) is a movie of them moving, with backlight.
7. Here are pictures of their undersides and their internal structures.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
8. Whenever I pull some out of the water and put them into a tupperware with the same water, they only survive for around 24 hours, after which they seem to disintegrate.  Here is a picture of about 20 of the worms after about 24 hours, the bulk of them have halfway-decomposed and form a heap in the upper right.  After another day it'll just look like debris in the water, you wouldn't even recognize that there were worms in it.  There is a piece of bacon in there because some suggested putting it there to test if they were leeches, but this disintegration happens repeatably and regardless of the bacon; please ignore the bacon.
   [image]
9. Someone suggested that they are trematodes, but there are no snails, frogs, or other creatures in the storage and collection sections of the water system;  we have looked very closely.  There may be something within a 30-foot section of pipe, but we doubt it.

Can you help us identify this creature?  Even just possible families of creatures or general categories would be helpful for us.

Comment: My first thought, based on the two "points", is that they're [slugs](http://www.manandmollusc.net/advanced_introduction/amphidromus.html), but I think most water slugs live in salt water. [This page](http://www.seaslugforum.net/find/16865) seems to suggest that freshwater slugs are all tropical, but might have a useful lead.

Comment: Are leeches supposed to like bacon ? I thought they needed fresh blood.

Comment: @bli - leeches are attracted to odors as well. In swampy areas, it's not uncommon to find a leech or two on a carcass that's been in the water.

Comment: @JeffAmelang Thanks for good photography and description effort.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am not too sure but this looks like *Polycelis sierrensis*.

Though it is apparent that the worm in your pictures is a tricladid planarian, I was not too sure about the species and the geographical distribution.

However, from the [Smithsonian list of freshwater planarians in North America](http://www.sil.si.edu/smithsoniancontributions/Zoology/pdf_hi/SCTZ-0476.pdf), I deduced that this should be *Polycelis sierrensis* which is found in California and Nevada ([Kenk ,1973](http://www.sil.si.edu/smithsoniancontributions/zoology/pdf_hi/SCTZ-0135.pdf)).

The [EOL page](http://eol.org/pages/4976580/overview) on this species also concurs with the geographical distribution. Moreover, the shape and dimensions of the worm, as described in EOL, matches with that of the ones you have got.

I could not find a picture of *P. sierrensis* but this is how a general *Polycelis* looks like:

[image]

Comment: Wow, a google image search for *Polycelis sierrensis* shows this image as the first result, at least for me.

Comment: @user151841 Same here. But the caption just says *Polycelis sp.* but this one does look like the worms in the question.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer, WYSIWYG.  We really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

The overall shape appears to match that of a [**flatworm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatworm) or [**planarian**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarian), but those don't have eyestalks. Also, in the images you posted, none of the worms appear to have the characteristic eyespots of a flatworm, although they DO look planarian-like in some photos:

[image]

If they didn't look so thin, I'd say they were common [**garden slugs**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug). We get them all the time down in Southeast Texas, and they're attracted to humid areas, especially wetness. They usually have thicker bodies, though:

[image]

I've never put salt on a planarian before, but the behavior you describe is exactly what happens when a common slug hits salt. They curl up into what looks like a wad of gum, then shrivel up into a blackened husk. On the other hand, slugs are definitely NOT mountainous creatures. And they're definitely NOT leeches, which we also get down in Southeast Texas.

**Based on your location and the images, you're probably looking at some sort of freshwater planarian. They're most likely in the source spring itself.**

Answer (score 5):

Their capacity to elongate / contract and their two head lobes make me think they are [Planarians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarian).

The two points  on their heads must be their eyes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_eye_in_invertebrates#Ocelli_or_eye_spots